# Наклонить блок без наклона содержимого

Tags: html, css, css3, transform

У меня есть div, в котором находится картинка. Как сделать так, чтобы при наклоне с помощью свойства transform: skewX() картинка оставалась ровной, т.е. без наклона?

Comment: У картинки  transform: skewX(-deg)

Comment: Задать картинке обратную трансформацию.

Answer (score 2):

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: blue; /*Незабываем про фон контейнера*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  transform: skewX(45deg); /*Поворачиваем блок*/  
  overflow: hidden; /*Чтобы картинка не выходила за контейнер*/ 
}

div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  transform: skewX(-45deg); /*Возращаем в первоначальное положение картинку*/  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://avatarko.ru/img/kartinka/18/frukt_yabloko_17951.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```